# SSRS managed shared subscriptions data from from database

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, etl

While running an ETL process we need to pause the shared managed SSRS subscriptions  and then enable them and run them accordingly when our ETL has progressed. In order to do that we take a backup of the ReportServer.dbo.Schedule  table just before we pause the subscriptions and we compare it with the time that we reach the proper state of our ETL (just after we enable them back). Our reporting services are the ones from sql server 2012 embedded in Sharepoint.

The problem here is that it seems that ReportServer.dbo.Schedule some times has NULL in the NextRunTime even though it does have a schedule set.  From some testing we saw that if we connect to the sharepoint portal that we have with the ssrs reports then the nextruntime gets populated succesfully but if for example on a sunday , noone connects to that portal , then the nextRunTime remains with NULLs..

Anyone has encourred that before and has any idea on how to overcome that issue ??

Thanks for any help,
Dimitris

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is in the `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity` table? Or obfuscated in the `sp_help_job` sproc? edit: Check out this [post on another site](https://am2.co/2016/02/xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs_alt/)

Comment: Will try to investigate this direction as well. Though if the schedule table in the ssrs database was working properly this would have been straight forward. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I agree that these tables are very confusing and don't seem to be reliable, but unfortunately that's all that MS has given us to work with, as far as I know.

Comment: So, i am using the following query to compare the next run time from the Schedule table and from the jobActivity and they don't match as as mentioned before the Schedule table is wrong (not refreshed properly), though the jobactivity seems to be accurate and hence i will proceed with that :

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
       s.Name,
       s.LastRunTime LastRunTime_schedule,
       s.NextRunTime NextRunTime_schedule,
       s3.next_scheduled_run_date next_scheduled_run_date_jobActivity, GETDATE() AS regdate
FROM ReportingService.dbo.Schedule s WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs s2 WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON CAST(s.ScheduleID AS sysname) = s2.name
           AND s.EventType = 'SharedSchedule'
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity s3 WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON s2.job_id = s3.job_id;